# how to call static async function from the class that has instance created already?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, constructor

handler class has process that i am trying to call by passing required params but it looks like i can not do that , any idea what would be correct approach in below scenario ?

Why i cant do GetAccountBalanceHandler .process in main ?

handler.ts

```
    export class GetAccountBalanceHandler extends Controller {
        public static async process(@Request() request: any,
                                    response: any): Promise<any> {
            try {
                const instance = new GetAccountBalanceHandler();
                const data = await instance.execute(request);
                response.status(200);
                response.send(data);
            } catch (err) {
                response.status(200);
                response.send(err.message);
            }

        }

        constructor() {
            super();
        }

// execute stuff
    }
```

main.ts

```
import {handler} "./handler"
  export class GetAccountBalanceController extends Controller {
    public static async process(@Request() request: ExpressRequest,
                                response: ExpressResponse): Promise<any> {
        try {
            const instance = new GetAccountBalanceController();
            const data = await this.BalanceResponse(request);
            response.status(200);
            response.send(data);
        } catch (err) {
            response.status(200);
            response.send(err.message);
        }

    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
   private async BalanceResponse(_request: any): Promise<any> {
        return await GetAccountBalanceHandler .process(_request);
    }

}
```

Comment: Static methods do not have access to an instance of the class as `this`.  Why are you doing `await this.BalanceResponse(request)` instead of `await instance.BalanceResponse(request)`?

Comment: @jcalz yes i noticed that i wil fix that in handler but my question is what would be best approach to call handler process from another class

Comment: Make `BalanceResponse()` static also?  I'm not really sure what your use case is here.